# tradingview pine script about change macd line color

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

excuse me ,i am code beginner

i want to change my macdline color

when the new macdline taller than last macdlie

it will appear color green
if short ,its will be color red,

my original code:

```html
indicator(title="Moving Average Convergence Divergence", shorttitle="MACD", timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

fast_length = input(title="Fast Length", defval=12)
slow_length = input(title="Slow Length", defval=26)
src = input(title="Source", defval=close)
signal_length = input.int(title="Signal Smoothing",  minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 9)
sma_source = input.string(title="Oscillator MA Type",  defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
sma_signal = input.string(title="Signal Line MA Type", defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])

macdline = fast_length - slow_length
macdlinecolor = if macdline[0] > macdline[1]
    macdlinecolor = color.green
else
    macdlinecolor = color.red


col_macd = input(#2962FF, "MACD Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="MACD")
col_signal = input(#FF6D00, "Signal Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="Signal")
col_grow_above = input(#26A69A, "Above   Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_fall_above = input(#B2DFDB, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_grow_below = input(#FFCDD2, "Below Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
col_fall_below = input(#FF5252, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Below")

fast_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, fast_length) : ta.ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, slow_length) : ta.ema(src, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = sma_signal == "SMA" ? ta.sma(macd, signal_length) : ta.ema(macd, signal_length)
hist = macd - signal
hline(0, "Zero Line", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
plot(hist, title="Histogram", style=plot.style_columns, color=(hist>=0 ? (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_above : col_fall_above) : (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_below : col_fall_below)))
plot(macd, title="MACD", color=macdlinecolor)
plot(signal, title="Signal", color=col_signal)
```

but its wrong, how to i fix mycode?
please QQ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have calculated the color based on macd length. You will have to calculate it using actual macd. Example below

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Moving Average Convergence Divergence", shorttitle="MACD", timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

fast_length = input(title="Fast Length", defval=12)
slow_length = input(title="Slow Length", defval=26)
src = input(title="Source", defval=close)
signal_length = input.int(title="Signal Smoothing",  minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 9)
sma_source = input.string(title="Oscillator MA Type",  defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
sma_signal = input.string(title="Signal Line MA Type", defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])

macdline = fast_length - slow_length



col_macd = input(#2962FF, "MACD Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="MACD")
col_signal = input(#FF6D00, "Signal Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="Signal")
col_grow_above = input(#26A69A, "Above   Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_fall_above = input(#B2DFDB, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_grow_below = input(#FFCDD2, "Below Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
col_fall_below = input(#FF5252, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Below")

fast_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, fast_length) : ta.ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, slow_length) : ta.ema(src, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
macdlinecolor =  macd[0] > macd[1] ? color.green : color.red
signal = sma_signal == "SMA" ? ta.sma(macd, signal_length) : ta.ema(macd, signal_length)
hist = macd - signal
hline(0, "Zero Line", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
plot(hist, title="Histogram", style=plot.style_columns, color=(hist>=0 ? (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_above : col_fall_above) : (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_below : col_fall_below)))
plot(macd, title="MACD", color=macdlinecolor)
plot(signal, title="Signal", color=col_signal)
```